# IOS Automation: Is there a way to 'refresh' the Element Tree (Or whatever 'Instruments' thinks it can and cannot access)?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, ipad, automation

Ok, this is my first time posting, I hope I can accurately explain what's going on , but here's the deal, I have a page on an iPad app I'm working on that has a set of widgets (they display numbered statistics on one side, and a graphical representation on the other). When I pull up this page and log the element tree, I can see the statistic side of the widgets, but not the graphical side (this is good cause the graphical side isn't seen by the user yet). However, when I switch to the graphical side (via an icon) and log the element tree again, it still only shows the statistics side.

Normally, I would think that I need to better identify the graphical side, but, if I restart 'Instruments' and quickly flip over to the graphical side, THEN log the element tree, I see the graphical side, and not the statistics side.

A quick visualization could be:
Start Instruments > Stats Side > Log Tree = Stats side > Flip to graph side > Log Tree = Stats side

Start Instruments > Quickly Flip to Graph Side > Log Tree = Graph Side > Flip to stats side > Log Tree = Graph side

So, finally, I need a way to be able to access those elements whenever they appear, so is there a way to refresh the log tree, or is there a cache of the elements that's preventing me from 'seeing' the newly visible elements?

Thanks in advance!

(ps I tagged 'objective-c' cause that's what the app is written in)

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess. Content of your page is wrapped into CollectionView.
If yes then I have so much pain with similar issues.

1. I don't aware of any way to update 'the cache'
2. If you can't see anything in CollectionView (it contains 0 elements), most likely your collectionView returns zero for: `-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewnumberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
   *Actually, I'm not sure if this can be cause in your case, since you do see elements after manual navigation through app.*
3. Be preparedthat with CollectionView you'll face with duplicate cells and cells
   currently invisible. CollectionView have complicated memory
   management under the hood, for example, invisible objects are not
   deallocated but are hold for later use. For some reason Instruments
   doesn't know that and shows all the objects regardless of their
   visibility.